# DataFrame: convert a date column to specific format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a date columns in a DF like **"FY19 Jun"**.
How to convert the data format to 2019-01-01

Comment: What does "FY" stand for? [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) is a designated function for that, but I doubt it can recognize your format.

Comment: it stands for Fiscal Year.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['FY19 Jun']})

df['converted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='FY%y %b')
```

output:

```
       date  converted
0  FY19 Jun 2019-06-01
```

If you want the start of year, ignore the month:

```
df['converted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.extract(r'FY(\d+)', expand=False), format='%y')
```

output:

```
       date  converted
0  FY19 Jun 2019-01-01
```

Comment: That doesn't return `2019-01-01`. Probably a typo from OP? Also, fiscal year is a bit different.

Comment: @Quang right, I thought it was `06`. I provided an alternative. Not familiar with fiscal years though...